# Symfony php rendering

Tags: php, symfony

I am new in Symfony3, I used Twig to render a template and all was fine, but when I wanted to switch to PHP rendering I got error:

My class :

```
class Testdb extends  Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/testdb")
     *
     */
    public function testing()
    {
        //return $this->render('testdb.html.twig',array('result'=>$result));
        return $this->render('testdb.html.php',array('result'=>$result));
    }

}
```

I put my testdb.html.php in app/Resources/views/
and I edited my config.yml :

```
templating:
    engines: ['twig','php']
```

The when I browse `ttp://127.0.0.1:8000/testdb` I get `The template "testdb.html.php" does not exist`

Comment: Does https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15272 fix it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render the template, which is inside your application, or at least, specify in which bundle/app your template is.

```
return $this->render(
    'AppBundle:Default:testdb.html.php',
    array('result'=>$result)
);
```

Where AppBundle is the name of your app, and Default is the directory where is located your tempalte.